# Redirect user once function processed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to code igniter and I'm wondering how I can redirect a user back to the previous view and display a success or error message after they have submitted a form.

Here is my view

```
<div id="modal">
    <?php echo form_open('additem/insert', array('id'=>'insert')); ?> 
    <div class="field">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?=(isset($_GET['title'])) ? $_GET['title'] : ''?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="link">Link:</label>
        <input type="text" name="raw_link" value="<?=(isset($_GET['link'])) ? $_GET['link'] : ''?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="title">Additional Info: <span class="tip">(size or colour)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="additional_info" />
        <input type="hidden" name="fb_user_id" value="<?=$_SESSION['data']['fb_user_id']?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my controller

```
class Additem extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('list_model');

    $this->load->view('modal/add-item');
}

public function insert() {

    $data = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id', TRUE),
        'title' => $this->input->post('title', TRUE),
        'raw_link' => $this->input->post('raw_link', TRUE),
        'additional_info' => $this->input->post('additional_info', TRUE),
        'fb_user_id' => $this->input->post('fb_user_id', TRUE)
    );

    $this->load->model('list_model');
    $this->list_model->add_list_item($data);
}
```

}

Here is model

```
function add_list_item($data) {

    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->query("INSERT list_items (fb_user_id, added, title, raw_link, additional_info) VALUES(".$this->db->escape($data['fb_user_id']).", NOW(), ".$this->db->escape($data['title']).", ".$this->db->escape($data['raw_link']).", ".$this->db->escape($data['additional_info']).")");
    $this->db->query("UPDATE users SET num_items = num_items +1 WHERE fb_user_id = ".$this->db->escape($data['fb_user_id'])."");

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
       log_message('error', 'Unable to add list item for user '.$data['fb_user_id'].'');
    }
}
```

At the moment I am just presented with a blank screen with the url directing at the form location additem/insert, although everything works as should. I just want to redirect the user back to the previous view with a success or fail message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you are trying to search for something like this:

```
function add_list_item($data) {

    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->query("INSERT list_items (fb_user_id, added, title, raw_link, additional_info) VALUES(".$this->db->escape($data['fb_user_id']).", NOW(), ".$this->db->escape($data['title']).", ".$this->db->escape($data['raw_link']).", ".$this->db->escape($data['additional_info']).")");
    $this->db->query("UPDATE users SET num_items = num_items +1 WHERE fb_user_id = ".$this->db->escape($data['fb_user_id'])."");

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    $status = TRUE;
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
       log_message('error', 'Unable to add list item for user '.$data['fb_user_id'].'');
       $status = FALSE;
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Now, according to transaction status you can show the respective view:

```
public function insert() {

    $data = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id', TRUE),
        'title' => $this->input->post('title', TRUE),
        'raw_link' => $this->input->post('raw_link', TRUE),
        'additional_info' => $this->input->post('additional_info', TRUE),
        'fb_user_id' => $this->input->post('fb_user_id', TRUE)
    );

    $this->load->model('list_model');

    $status = $this->list_model->add_list_item($data);
    if ($status == TRUE)
    {
        // 1. you can show a view
        $this->load->view('success_view');

        // 2. or do a redirection
        redirect('success_controller', "refresh");
    }
    else
    {
         // 1. you can show a view
        $this->load->view('error_view');

        // 2. or do a redirection
        redirect('error_controller', "refresh");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends wether or not you want to go to a new controller once the form is filled out.
If not, I would do something like that :

```
function insert()
{

    //Load the appropriate files (as the form ..) ..
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //Put some form_validetaion rules .. you have to set it for each field
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if(!$this->form_validation->run())
    {
        // the there was an error in the form or the user didn't submit it yet
        //load your view and pass an error message, see the form validation page for that
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errorMessage', 'see the error message for each field');
        $this->load->view('form', $data);
    }else{
        //YOUR CODE HERE
        // the form hass successfully validated
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flashMessage', 'The has been validated successfully');
        redirect('"controller"/"function"');

    }


}
```